# Git undo alias not working properly

Tags: git, alias

Would like some help on making this alias work properly:

```
[alias]
    undo = "!f() { git reset --hard HEAD@{$1-1}; }; f"
```

The goal is to be able to execute:

`git undo` with no parameters and have it revert to the prior action (HEAD@{1})

`git undo 2` would roll back to the 2nd prior action

When I execute it, I'm not seeing the expected behavior:

**git undo**

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@{-1}': unknown revision or path not in
>   the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like
>   this: 'git  [...] -- [...]'

**git undo 2**

> warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to Fri, 18 Mar 2016 12:00:10
>   -0700. warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to Fri, 18 Mar 2016 12:00:10 -0700. HEAD is now at 66b5b26 Initial commit

After calling `git undo 2` the latest reflog entry shows:

> 66b5b26 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{2-1}

How do I set this alias up properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you, you want it to behave like this:

```
git undo                  # HEAD@{1}
git undo 1                # HEAD@{1}
git undo 5                # HEAD@{5}
```

Then I believe this should work, assuming a shell like bash or zsh:

```
undo = "!f() { git reset --hard HEAD@{${1-1}}; }; f"
```

If you want to see what it will do without it doing anything, just stick `echo` in front of `git reset` in the alias, and it will show you what it would have run.

As was mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093388/2449905), and warrants mentioning here too, this will silently drop local changes in the working directory, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you are after.  I'm assuming you are looking for these expansions:

```
git undo    ==>  git reset --hard HEAD@{0}
git undo 1  ==>  git reset --hard HEAD@{0}
git undo 2  ==>  git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
git undo 3  ==>  git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
```

If that's what you are looking for, you can use

```
undo = "!f() { git reset --hard HEAD@{$((${1:-1} - 1))}; }; f"
```

Note that this alias is rather dangerous.  It will silently drop all local changes in your working directory.

Comment: +1 for the note about it silently dropping local changes. I'll probably convert this to a shell script that asks for confirmation before continuing based on that point.